# Django parse data to model without storing

Tags: python, django, django-serializer, python-dataclasses, data-class

I was wondering if there is a way to parse a json to an object of the model class without having any databse interaction.
If we do what I want to do without django I could serialize a Json into an object class, for example with some help of [marshmallow_dataclass](https://github.com/lovasoa/marshmallow_dataclass)

```
@dataclass
class Example:
    id : int
    name : str
```

If I do it with a django model and serializer I do it with a standard model serializer and a model class:

```
serializer = ExampleSerializer(data=data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
serializer.save()
```

So now the question is if there is a way to do combine them. Reason for this, I have a shared model across different applications. Now since some are just processing the data, with there is no need to store it, which I currently do but is a performance drawback. At the same time with combining them I want to achieve to not have to maintain a model and a class with the same fields.
Therefore how can I use the model class to parse the data to without having to store them in the database?

Comment: How complicated are your models? Do they have any related fields)? If all of the fields on your serializer are valid properties of your model I think you can just do `obj = ExampleModel(**serializer.validated_data)` after calling `serializer.is_valid()`.

Comment: yes I looked into this, but they have many related tables, also containing related fields themselves again, so it is important to also be able to have the related objects, which from my research seems not able to be done with your proposed solution

Comment: Correct, and without saving things to the database you will only really be able to handle foreign keys from the model in question (not many-to-manys or reverse relationships) since anything else will involve querysets anyways. If you know the list of foreign keys you want to populate you could pop those values out of validated data and populate them separately, or introspect the model metadata similar to how DRF does it to determine what fields are FKs: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L934

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you are looking to have combined validation for the pre-defined model classes, without actually using the django provided methods of having to create a model instance.
One interesting method of achieving this is by using `pydantic-django` for this task.
You can create a pydantic model_class to parse the data as is required which will ensure all the validations done for you.
For instance, if your example model is as below:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    f1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

the related pydantic class for validation can be:

```
from pydantic_django import ModelSchema
class ExampleSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Config:
        model = Example
```

Comment: thanks that looks really what I need, will give it a try